Command 'SFDX: Launch Apex Replay Debugger with Current File' resulted in an error

Summary
Issue launching an Apex Replay Debugger session with a downloaded apex log.
Steps To Reproduce:

VSCode Command Palette - SFDX: Get Apex Debug Logs
VSCode Command Palette - SFDX: Launch Apex Replay Debugger with Current File

Expected result
It should initiate an Apex Replay Debugger session with a yellow highlighted line at the start of the debug log.
Actual result

Additional information

The debug log in the org has been generated for my user.
The trace flag information:
60.0 APEX_CODE,FINEST;APEX_PROFILING,NONE;CALLOUT,NONE;DB,INFO;NBA,NONE;SYSTEM,NONE;VALIDATION,NONE;VISUALFORCE,FINER;WAVE,NONE;WORKFLOW,NONE
I have already tried setting up a new SFDX project, Re-authorizing sandbox

Salesforce Extension Version in VS Code: Salesforce Extension Pack (Expanded) v60.5.1
SFDX CLI Version: @salesforce/cli/2.35.6 darwin-arm64 node-v20.11.1
Java Version:
openjdk 17.0.6 2023-01-17 LTS OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.40+19-CA (build 17.0.6+10-LTS) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.40+19-CA (build 17.0.6+10-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
OS and version: macOS Sonomo 14.3.1 (23D60)
VS Code version:
Version: 1.88.0 Commit: 5c3e652f63e798a5ac2f31ffd0d863669328dc4c Date: 2024-04-03T13:28:09.495Z Electron: 28.2.8 ElectronBuildId: 27744544 Chromium: 120.0.6099.291 Node.js: 18.18.2 V8: 12.0.267.19-electron.0 OS: Darwin arm64 23.3.0
